# How to change the game control?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a game which is a car moving forward on pressing the up arrow and stops on pressing the down arrow. I need to change the game control. I want to use a matlab file as input.
This file contains a function, when the function = 1 car moves when it's 0 the car stops.

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
move = cont.actuators["move"]
pressup = cont.sensors["up"]
pressdown = cont.sensors["down"]
speed = move.dLoc[1]

if pressup.positive:
  speed = speed + 0.05
  move.dLoc = [0.0, speed, 0.0]
  cont.activate(move)

elif pressdown.positive:
  speed = 0
  cont.deactivate(move)
  move.dLoc = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Indirect Control

I suggest to first exchange the keyboard sensors by message sensors. You do not even need to change your car controlling code.

[image]

to

[image]

To make it working, you now need a "user input provider" (other object) to send the new messages.

[image]

Note: the True Level Triggering. This is necessary to continuous send the messages as long as the key is held.

Now your game should act as it did before

## File input

Now you can add a request provider that does not listen to the keyboard, but reads a file and sends according messages with the right timing. Be aware this is a continuous process. You should send a message (of on subject) just once per frame.

You need to process file operations via Python. How to do that is a different topic.